# The Requests streaming example does not work in my environment

Tags: python, python-requests, twitter-streaming-api

I've been trying to consume the Twitter Streaming API using Python Requests.

There's a [simple example](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#streaming-requests) in the documentation:

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.post('https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json',
    data={'track': 'requests'}, auth=('username', 'password'))

for line in r.iter_lines():
    if line: # filter out keep-alive new lines
        print json.loads(line)
```

When I execute this, the call to `requests.post()` never returns. I've experimented and proved that it is definitely connecting to Twitter and receiving data from the API. However,  instead of returning a response object, it just sits there consuming as much data as Twitter sends. Judging by the code above, I would expect `requests.post()` to return a response object with an open connection to Twitter down which I could continue to receive realtime results.

(To prove it was receiving data, I connected to Twitter using the same credentials in another shell, whereupon Twitter closed the first connection, and the call returned the response object. The `r.content` attribute contained all the backed up data received while the connection was open.)

The documentation makes no mention of any other steps required to cause `requests.post` to return before consuming all the supplied data. Other people seem to be using similar code without encountering this problem, e.g. [here](http://kracekumar.com/post/19556427690/n00bs-epic-research-on-twitters-streaming-api-on).

I'm using:

- Python 2.7
- Ubuntu 11.04
- Requests 0.14.0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to switch off prefetching, which I think is a parameter that changed defaults:

```
r = requests.post('https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json',
    data={'track': 'requests'}, auth=('username', 'password'),
    prefetch=False)

for line in r.iter_lines():
    if line: # filter out keep-alive new lines
        print json.loads(line)
```

Note that as of requests 1.x the parameter has been renamed, and now you use [`stream=True`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow):

```
r = requests.post('https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json',
    data={'track': 'requests'}, auth=('username', 'password'),
    stream=True)

for line in r.iter_lines():
    if line: # filter out keep-alive new lines
        print json.loads(line)
```

Comment: Thanks! I've just submitted a pull request to get the docs updated.

Answer (score 5):

Ah, I found the answer by reading the code. At some point, a prefetch parameter was added to the post method (and other methods, I assume).

I just needed to add a `prefetch=False` kwarg to `requests.post()`.

Comment: Further reading suggests prefetch has been a parameter for a while, but its default value was changed to True in version 0.13.6.

Comment: :-) Just as I was typing up the answer for you. :-P